# What are the best practices for cookie consent?

Tags: users, cookies

Recently I read a couple of articles' about cookies consent and made a conclusion that cookie consent is important product's part which might lead into bad user experience if it's designed poorly.

**My question is:** when it comes to cookies, what practices should be used to ensure users are not frightened on a website? Should cookies be presented in a modal with background tint, or should they be fixed at the bottom? Should users be provided with a lot of content in the cookie consent, or should it be as brief as possible?

Comment: I vote to reopen because the duplicate is extremely old, the laws have changed, the question is localized only to EU and most important it doesn't have any accepted answer. Edited to avoid opinionated questions